# Try block doesn't prevent exception

Tags: exception, try-catch

I put part of code in try block to prevent exception and hanle it in catch block. But when app is executed exception is thrown. Why is it not prevented?

```
        private void btnAddCriteria_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Criteria root = trvMenu.SelectedItem as Criteria;
            if (root != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(root.criterias[0].criterias[0] != null)
                        MessageBox.Show("Max depth");
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    if (txtNode.Text != "")
                    {
                        root.criterias.Add(new Criteria(txtNode.Text));
                    }
                    else MessageBox.Show("Enter Node text");
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are catching and handling `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but application is throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

You should change your code to handle `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or both.